# MySQL dump export version mismatch

Tags: mysql, dump

I'm trying to export my database, but it says that my `mysqldump.exe` is version `8.0.27` while my server is `10.4.24`.

I can't find a `mysqldump.exe` in that version, so what should I do?
Is there a way to "unupdate" my database?

[Dump warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbqlP.png)

[Dump error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAP3p.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should download the good exe and go to: `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Administrator` -> Path to `Mysqldumptool`:
Look for file **mysqldump.exe** in your MySQL Server installation folder (it could be: mysql/bin/). Then click it, and OK. After that try to do the backup.

Comment: Even better ... download Microsoft Workbench and edit your database like it was an Excel file .. including the ability to import and export or straight out dump the data you want with mouse clicks.  If you prefer to deal with the command line have at it, but its kind of nice to let the GUI do the handy work for you to save time.